# angular service into app config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**app.js**

```
        angular
            .module('yelp',['ngRoute'])  //creating  module
            .config(config);

        config.$inject=['$routeProvider','YelpService']; //YelpService is unknown here
        function config($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider
                .when('/restaurants',{
                    templateUrl:'partials/restaurants.html',
                    controller:'RestaurantsController',
                    controllerAs:'rstrntsCtrl',
                    resolve:{
                        getRestaurants:getRestaurants
                    }
                });
        }

        function getRestaurants(YelpService){
            // i need route params here
        }
```

**YelpService.js**

```
    angular
        .module('yelp')  //using already created module
            .factory('YelpService',YelpService);

    YelpService.$inject=['$http'];
    function YelpService($http){

        var factory={
        }

        return factory;
    }
```

I loaded app.js file first and then yelpService.js file. Since service is loaded later i think it is not available to inject. If i load service file first, it causes an error, since the module in created in config file. How to overcome this. Moreover in config file how to get routeparams in **getRestaurants** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For yelp use the provider call `YelpServiceProvider`.
For the resolve just wrap in a function and inject the desired functionality.

```
angular
        .module('yelp',['ngRoute'])  //creating  module
        .config(config);

    config.$inject=['$routeProvider','YelpServiceProvider']; //YelpService is unknown here
    function config($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/restaurants',{
                templateUrl:'partials/restaurants.html',
                controller:'RestaurantsController',
                controllerAs:'rstrntsCtrl',
                resolve:{
                    restaurants:function($routeParams, YelpService) {
                      return getRestaurants($routeParams, YelpService);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    function getRestaurants($routeParams, YelpService){
        // i need route params here
    }
```

Resolve is used to, well, resolve your data. So the left hand assignment would not be a function name as you have perhaps meant but the variable list of items (a promise actually).

Then in your controller after having injected 'restaurants':

```
this.restaurants; // or $scope.restaurants if you are not using controllerAs
```